# Scaling figures / graphics inside table

Tags: tables, graphics, scaling

I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Name & Number of crossings & Arf invariant \\ 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../images/unknot.jpg}  & 0 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which produces a table. But the picture does not get scaled. Why? And how can I make it scale the graphic? Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is nothing in tabular code that should affect the scale, if you remave all the table/tabular markup and just have `\includegraphics{../images/unknot.jpg}\par\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../images/unknot.jpg}` are they the same size?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes indeed they are. I'm confused. It used to scale.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks loads. Must be impossible to scale jpegs. It works with a png.

Comment: It is possible to scale jpg's (I just tested to make sure). But it could fail for special jpg's if e.g. they don't contain the correct picture size informations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot, that's useful to know!

Comment: anyway if the internal image scaling fails, most likely wrapping it in \scalebox{0.5}{\includegraphics... will do the trick

Comment: @MattN. Which graphics driver and which TeX compiler you are using?